# Which jar files do I need to read and write values from a Excel File using POI from Java?

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I want to read values and write values from an Excel file or .xls file using POI from Java. I don't need the source code; I can write that.

I have already looked around on the [developers site](http://poi.apache.org), but there were lots of files. Which jar file(s) do I need to download so that `import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;` will work?

Comment: Consider using [maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) for resolving dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Go to the [developers download page](http://poi.apache.org/download.html)
- Then in binary distribution link click on [poi-bin-3.8-20120326.zip](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/poi/release/bin/poi-bin-3.8-20120326.zip)
- Now click on the first link (http://apache.techartifact.com/mirror/poi/release/bin/poi-bin-3.8-20120326.zip)
- Then, in Eclipse, add it to your external jar library.

Answer (score 3):

Currently I am using poi-3.8-20120326.jar. That's it I needed, no other jars. On your [link](http://poi.apache.org/download.html), download poi-bin-3.8-20120326.zip

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have downloaded this one and already tried but it is still showing errors so i think i need to set any path. what do you think?

Comment: @VikasGupta 1) Put your poi jar in WEB-INF/lib folder if it is web app otherwise if it is desktop app, keep it in your jars folder. 2) Right click on your project in Project Explorer in eclipse>> then click on Build Path>>Configure Build Path. 3) Window will open, it contains Source, Projects, Libraries etc tabs. Click on Libraries tab, Click on "Add Jars" button, add poi jar And click on OK. That's it.

Comment: @VikasGupta : did you go through this procedure? if yes Refresh your workspace.

Comment: actually this is a web app but right now i am trying to read values from a file which is on system, and i have been through your procedure when i click on add jar button there is no option to select my .zip file, so i had to go for add external jars, and i tried that already. so i guess i am again where i started. :(

Comment: @VikasGupta extract zip file(using winzip/winrar) and use jar file from it. You can not add zip file.

Answer (score 2):

You should get what you need in the POI 3.8 Available [here](http://poi.apache.org/download.html#POI-3.8).

Comment: I have downloaded this one and already tried but it is still showing errors so i think i need to set any path. what do you think?

Comment: @VikasGupta: If you are using an IDE (which I recommend, like Eclipse and Netbeans) you should be able to get it working by adding the JAR files in the `lib` folder of your project. If you are not, you can the file to where your class path is pointing. If you have any difficulties, you should be able to get plenty of information online.

Comment: The import org.apache cannot be resolved

Answer (score 0):

use this poi-scratchpad-3.6-20091214.jar

Comment: please post the link and tell me what other changes i need to run my program like do i need to set any path

Comment: @VikasGupta If you are using eclipse, add it to classpath from Project's build path. Start using its API.

Comment: please tell me step by step procedure

Comment: This is incorrect - HSSF is in the core/main jar, and the scratchpad jar on its own is never enough as it depends on the core/main jar

Answer (score -1):

[This is tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/apache_poi_environment.htm) shows a set of jars to use to access Excel. I use:

- poi-3.17.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.17.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar
- xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
- commons-collections4-4.1.jar